# Django: How to sort a ModelForm's Many2ManyField (Select Tag) according to the object's __unicode__() value?

Tags: python, django

As stated in the title.

Answer (score 0):

The sort would have to be done in Python since the database has no idea what you're doing in `__unicode__()`.  So you'd have to retrieve all of the related model instances into a list, sort the list using the `__unicode__()` value of the instances, and then use that list wherever you want.

The following document has a number of methods for sorting in python: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/